# Windows.GetRValue accepts cardinals but TColor is integer

Tags: delphi

I need to pass a color to GetRValue which accepts cardinals. However, TColor is integer and I get sometimes a range check error. Should I just trim my color to 0 if it is negative?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Negative values indicate that you are passing special color values like `clWindow` to `GetRValue`. That's a mistake. You need to call `ColorToRGB` first in order to convert to a true RGB value. A true RGB value, stored in a 32 bit integer, will never be negative.

```
R := GetRValue(ColorToRGB(Color));
```

One other explanation is that you are putting ARGB values into a `TColor`. That's also a mistake because `TColor` does not hold an alpha channel.